# Serialized list erase content when changing focus on Unity custom EditorWindow

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-editor

I've a custom unity editor window that displays a list of this type of objects:

```
[Serializable]
public class CustomAdditionalData
{
    public string PayloadKey;
    public string PayloadValue;
}
```

The list is correctly displayed, but when I type on any of the fields, if I change the focus to another field, it erase the content of the previous one, this is how I build the editor window:

```
#if UNITY_EDITOR
using System;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Tiles
{
    public class CustomEditorWindow : EditorWindow
    {
        [SerializeField]
        private List<CustomAdditionalData> payloadList = new List<CustomAdditionalData>();
        
        [MenuItem("Tools/Custom Window")]
        public static void ShowWindow()
        {
            var desiredDockWindow = Type.GetType("UnityEditor.InspectorWindow,UnityEditor.dll");
            GetWindow<CustomEditorWindow>("Custom Window", true, desiredDockWindow).Show();
        }
        
        private void OnGUI()
        {
            ScriptableObject target = this;
            var so = new SerializedObject(target);
            var payloadListProperty = so.FindProperty(nameof(payloadList));
            EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(payloadListProperty, true);
            so.ApplyModifiedProperties();
            EditorUtility.SetDirty(target); //I also tried without setting target to dirty, it does the same :(

            EditorGUILayout.Space();
            if (GUILayout.Button("Simulate")) {
                SimulateButton();
            }
        }

        private void SimulateButton()
        {
            var payloadDict = payloadList.ToDictionary<CustomAdditionalData, string, object>(payloadAdditionalData => payloadAdditionalData.PayloadKey, payloadAdditionalData => payloadAdditionalData.PayloadValue);
            //Do something with the payloadDict
        }
    }
}
#endif
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OnGUI()` method is called very often, not only once ([you can find an explanation here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnGUI.html)). And you are creating a new instance of `ScriptableObject` in every call.

It looks like it just cannot have a chance to be saved. You should create the object you want to edit only once. For example, in your `ShowWindow` method.

Comment: This is partially correct but I've accepted anyway cause it's ALMOST the answer.
The only thing to add here is that the object CAN'T be initialized on the ShowWindow method cause it's static, and "this" cannnot be referenced in a static method.

Answer (score 0):

Following @Morion advice, what I do now is to cache the so variable ONLY if it's null (to only do it once) using:

```
so ??= new SerializedObject(target);
```

This is the final code:

```
#if UNITY_EDITOR
using System;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Tiles
{
[Serializable]
public class CustomAdditionalData
{
    public string PayloadKey;
    public string PayloadValue;
}
    public class CustomEditorWindow : EditorWindow
    {
        [SerializeField]
        private List<CustomAdditionalData> payloadList = new List<CustomAdditionalData>();
        
        private SerializedObject so;

        [MenuItem("Tools/Custom Window")]
        public static void ShowWindow()
        {
            var desiredDockWindow = Type.GetType("UnityEditor.InspectorWindow,UnityEditor.dll");
            GetWindow<CustomEditorWindow>("Custom Window", true, desiredDockWindow).Show();
        }
        
        private void OnGUI()
        {
            so ??= new SerializedObject(target);
            var payloadListProperty = so.FindProperty(nameof(payloadList));
            EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(payloadListProperty, true);
            so.ApplyModifiedProperties();

            EditorGUILayout.Space();
            if (GUILayout.Button("Simulate")) {
                SimulateButton();
            }
        }

        private void SimulateButton()
        {
            var payloadDict = payloadList.ToDictionary<CustomAdditionalData, string, object>(payloadAdditionalData => payloadAdditionalData.PayloadKey, payloadAdditionalData => payloadAdditionalData.PayloadValue);
            //Do something with the payloadDict
        }
    }
}
#endif
```